# mensaje, 'python dejo de funcionar'

Tags: python, vscode

desarrollando mi programa en python en el visual studio code, en algunas ocaciones, no siempre, y de forma aleatoria, el programa ejecutado en la ventana de ms-dos me muestra estos dos mensajes

[image: Fig.1]

[image: Fig.2]

sin que me señale ninguna línea.
También lo he realizado bajo Ejecución y depuración del vsc y sucede lo mismo, los mismos mensajes de error y sin señalarme ninguna línea. En la columna de la izquierda del debug, tampoco me señala nada. Ya digo que es de forma aleatoria, ejecutando el código varias veces seguidas, unas funciona correctamente y otras no.
¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?
Gracias anticipadas.

Comment: Puedes adjuntar tu código? Sin saber que estás haciendo es prácticamente imposible entender por qué se está cerrando el proceso

Comment: El problemas es que no sé que parte del código esta 'fallando' porque no me indica nada, el poner todo el código no creo que ayude mucho, hay unas cuantas miles de lineas. Solo pregunto si os ha pasado alguna vez, y/o si hay otro método para hacer un debugger mas detallado o profundo. El programa tiene un poco de todo, pyqt5, mysql y soup. Gracias.

Comment: Puedes probar a montar tu proyecto en PyCharm Community a ver si te da más información o utilizar un logger para determinar en qué punto se para o revisar el visor de eventos de windows para intentar averiguar qué es lo que ha generado que se pare el proceso, pero tiene pinta de ser un problema de memoria

Comment: Gracias miraré como ponerlo en PyCharm. No habia pensado en lo de la memoria, había pensado en algo del soap, como es un raspado de una página. a lo mejor, puede ser que el soap en algunos momentos no le haya dado tiempo a recorrer toda la pagina, pero aun así tendría que dar error en alguna linea, y no lo hace. Quedo agradecido.